# Durandal Activation Data Array Passed In to Activate as Separated Values

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I am looking for a way to use DurandalJS `activateItem()` and pass in an array as the activation data, but it will come into the desired view model as separated values instead of an array.

```
var activator = activator.create();
var viewModel = new Instance();
var activatorParams = [1,2,3]

activator.activateItem(viewModel, activatorParams );
```

Inside of the `Instance` view model the `activate` looks like this.

```
self.activate = function(param1, param2, param3) { do stuff with parameters };
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Durandal doesn't support that, it will send your parameters over to your `activate` as is, so you should receive a single argument in your activate.

One option might be to just shape your argument as such (but with appropriate names, of course):

```
activator.activateItem(viewModel, { 
    firstParam: activatorParams[0], 
    secondParam: activatorParams[1],
    thirdParam: activatorParams[2]
});
```

and receive it as:

```
self.activate = function(activationData) { 
//do stuff with activationData.firstParam, etc.
};
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I currently understood it as well. I think I was fishing more for some creative ideas to handle this. I currently have some living code that has a list of parameters in the `activate` and was trying to think plausible ways to keep that code. It seems like refactoring is looming.

Comment: I see! Well, maybe someone else will post a more creative way for you to avoid having to change too much code. If not, you can always rename your current activate to something like internalActivate, and add an activate function that will translate the input into your n parameters and call it.